# Failed to instal APC via pecl install APC

Tags: php, centos, centos5

When I try to install APC via `pecl install APC-3.1.5`
or even `pecl install APC` I get following error when the package comes to the `make` command:

```
running: make
/bin/sh /var/tmp/pear-build-root/APC-3.1.5/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/var/tmp/APC -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-root/APC-3.1.5/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-root/APC-3.1.5/main -I/var/tmp/APC -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /var/tmp/APC/apc.c -o apc.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/var/tmp/APC -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-root/APC-3.1.5/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-root/APC-3.1.5/main -I/var/tmp/APC -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /var/tmp/APC/apc.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/apc.o
In file included from /var/tmp/APC/apc.c:44:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /var/tmp/APC/apc.c:44:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:37: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:38: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:44: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'pcre'
/var/tmp/APC/apc.c:369: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'pcre'
/var/tmp/APC/apc.c: In function 'apc_regex_compile_array':
/var/tmp/APC/apc.c:430: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'preg'
/var/tmp/APC/apc.c:430: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'preg'
/var/tmp/APC/apc.c:431: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'nreg'
/var/tmp/APC/apc.c:431: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'nreg'
/var/tmp/APC/apc.c: In function 'apc_regex_match_array':
/var/tmp/APC/apc.c:463: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'preg'
/var/tmp/APC/apc.c:463: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'preg'
/var/tmp/APC/apc.c:464: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'nreg'
/var/tmp/APC/apc.c:464: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'nreg'
make: *** [apc.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

I installed all possible missing things:

```
yum install php-devel httpd-devel
yum groupinstall ‘Development Tools’
yum groupinstall ‘Development Libraries’
```

And still nothing.

Answer (score 35):

Try

```
yum install pcre-devel
```

before installing APC.

On Debian use

```
aptitude install libpcre3-dev
```

instead.

Comment: +1 this worked for me, should be the accepted solution

Comment: worked like a charm...

Comment: +1 this worked for me, should be the accepted solution. Thanks

Comment: This fixed it for me too. +1 for accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would compile from source.  Make sure you delete anything that the package installers left behind.  You probably have old extension directories laying around from older php versions. rm -rf them and their contents so you wont have any confusion.

```
cd ~ 
mkdir setups
cd setups 
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/APC-3.1.9.tgz 
tar -xvf APC-3.1.9.tgz 
cd APC-3.1.9
phpize
./configure --enable-apc --enable-apc-mmap --with-apxs --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config
make
```

For the config= argument, run *which php*, and add *-config* to the result

If you get this error (Same as one you posted)

> In file included from
>   /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.5/apc.c:38:
>   /usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18:
>   error: pcre.h: No such file or
>   directory In file included from
>   /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.5/apc.c:38:
>   /usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:45:
>   error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm'
>   or '**attribute**' before '*' token
>   /usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:46:
>   error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm'
>   or '**attribute**' before '*' token
>   /usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:52:
>   error: expected
>   specifier-qualifier-list before 'pcre'
>   /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.5/apc.c:362:
>   error: expected
>   specifier-qualifier-list before 'pcre'
>   /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.5/apc.c: In
>   function 'apc_regex_compile_array':
>   /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.5/apc.c:419:
>   error: 'apc_regex' has no member named
>   'preg'
>   /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.5/apc.c:419:
>   error: 'apc_regex' has no member named
>   'preg'
>   /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.5/apc.c:420:
>   error: 'apc_regex' has no member named
>   'nreg'
>   /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.5/apc.c:420:
>   error: 'apc_regex' has no member named
>   'nreg' /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.5/apc.c:
>   In function 'apc_regex_match_array':
>   /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.5/apc.c:452:
>   error: 'apc_regex' has no member named
>   'preg'
>   /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.5/apc.c:452:
>   error: 'apc_regex' has no member named
>   'preg'
>   /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.5/apc.c:453:
>   error: 'apc_regex' has no member named
>   'nreg'
>   /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.5/apc.c:453:
>   error: 'apc_regex' has no member named
>   'nreg' make: *** [apc.lo] Error 1

Then you have to install pcre and make sure it's from the / directory or it will not install.

```
yum install pcre-devel

make
make install
```

Comment: If you get a warning about the --with-apxs flag, you can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are trying to install APC on a system running PHP < 5.2.x. Version 3.1 of APC requires 5.2.x. I'm assuming your running CentOS 5.5 which ships with PHP 5.1.x.

try compiling and installing APC 3.0.19 from http://pecl.php.net/package/APC. We have had success deploying APC 3.0 on our CentOS servers.

Comment: No I have php 5.3.3 installed and still the pecl wont install it correctly... i think their repo is  corrupted. I had as you suggested to manually compile it.

Comment: @sangoku : me too struck with the same. if you got any solution plz share here. my php version  is 5.3.2 and gets this error `procedure entry point pcre_exe could not be located`

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu:

```
aptitude install libpcre3-dev
```

And then:

```
pecl install apc
```

Comment: No new information (TM). Downvoting.

Comment: Thanks man. For Ubuntu users that's a useful information. I could not comment on the previous answer (comments are still disabled for me, i can only answer).

Comment: thanks. Could not find what is wrong with my ubuntu. Helped me.